# Determine if the month is almost over in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to figure out the best way to determine if a given Date is 10 days or less from the end of the month. I am basically building functionality that will display a message if the month is almost over. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose I could do: def c= new GregorianCalendar() if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > 20)

Comment: `Calendar.instance[ Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH ] > 20` would be more Groovy ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be something like:

```
def isEndOfMonth() {
  Calendar.instance.with {
    it[ DAY_OF_MONTH ] + 10 > getActualMaximum( DAY_OF_MONTH )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
def date = new Date();

// ten days is in the next month so we are near end of month
if ((date + 10).month != date.month) { 
    // write message
}
```

I'm a novice with groovy so I may have made a mistake with the syntax but the concept should be ok.

Comment: Thanks Don. I didn't even think about the plus method being an operator overide.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Groovy Date Page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN0545-Dates).

```
boolean isLessThanNDaysFromEndOfMonth(Date d, int n) {
  return (d + n).month != d.month
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Michael Rutherfurd's suggestion groovyfied:

```
Date.metaClass.isEndOfMonth = { 
    (delegate+10).month != delegate.month
}

new Date().isEndOfMonth()
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library is well worth exploring. The author of Joda time is the spec lead of [JSR-310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) which aims to provide a Java 7 alternative to the "old" Calendar/Date classes.

```
import org.joda.time.*

@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='joda-time', module='joda-time', version='1.6.2')
])

DateTime now = new DateTime()
DateTime monthEnd = now.monthOfYear().roundCeilingCopy()
Days tendays = Days.days(10)

if (Days.daysBetween(now, monthEnd).isLessThan(tendays)) {
    println "Month is nearly over"
}
else {
    println "Plenty of time left"
}
```